# Excel - доступ к ячейке из другой, ещё не сохраненной книги

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Приложение, как результат работы, записывает результат работы в Книга1 Лист1. Есть открытая Книга1, **не сохраненная на машине**.

Я хочу получить ячейку A1 листа Лист1 из Книги1 в другой книге. Какой формулой это сделать, не сохраняя Книгу1 на машине?

```
=[Книга1.xlsx]Лист1!$A$1
```

Не работает

Comment: Попробуйте указать полный путь к файлу `Книга1.xlsx`

Comment: @ВадимАлександру книга не сохранена на машине, соответственно пути к ней я не знаю, и задача получить из нее данные, не сохраняя ее.

Comment: Какой-то окольный путь... Результат нельзя получить напрямую, из Книги2? Или записать результат не в промежуточную Книгу1, а сразу - из обработчика (Книги0) в Книгу2?

Comment: @vikttur стороннему приложению выдающему Книгу1 нельзя задать файл выдачи. Оно просто выдает Книга1